# I want to show the images in ionic card next to each other

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I currently have an ionic card with pictures in it from the JSON object. I want to get the pictures next to each other. In the screenshot you can see what I want.
This is what I want:
https://gyazo.com/ae64a28f3b6f471a063eb43fed7fb535

This is what I have:
https://gyazo.com/942431243bf9db75b5bf8d945bb36ce2

There are 3 pictures but you cant see it.

```
 <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color ="primary">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Amcik</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-searchbar>
</ion-searchbar>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-12 col-md *ngFor="let item of items">
        <ion-card>
          <ion-item>
            <h2>{{ item.name }}</h2>
            <p>{{ item.count }} leerlingen</p>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item *ngFor="let i of item.items">
           <ion-avatar>
             <img src="{{i.avatar}}">
           </ion-avatar>
         </ion-item>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the css of `<ion-item>` and `<ion-avatar>` will also have an affect. So, I think you should use your own `<div>`s. Like this:

Instead of this:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let i of item.items">
    <ion-avatar>
        <img src="{{i.avatar}}">
    </ion-avatar>
</ion-item>
```

Use this:

```
<div style="display: inline-block;" *ngFor="let i of item.items">
    <img src={{i.avatar}}>
</div>
```

Solution is to use/try values of the css property `display`. Like `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Thank you sir! You really helped me!

Comment: Any idea how to make the pictures smaller?

Comment: Play around with `height` or `max-height`.

Comment: @HasanAliKaldirim Did you face any problem with the answer? Why suddenly unaccept the answer now after so many days

Comment: I didnt even notice that i did it sorry